# Can anyone recommend an Arcpy GUI?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, gui

Can anyone recommend a GUI for arcpy? So if I want to run my script as an exe with some blank text boxes(or text boxes with default entries), radio buttons, check boxes etc.

Answer (score 6):

The two most popular are [`Tkinter`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/) and [`wxPython`](http://www.wxpython.org/) with Tkinter probably the [easiest to set up and start programming with](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/gui.html#tkinter). There are other GUI options in that last link as well.

Running your script as a standalone .exe is a separate matter, and you may want to look at this link first as it has some gotchas playing nice with arcgisscripting: [Compiling Python Scripts that use ArcGIS Geoprocessing Tools?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8529/compiling-python-scripts-that-use-arcgis-geoprocessing-tools)

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to try Rapyd-Tk 
http://www.bitflipper.ca/rapyd/

This is a GUI form builder that uses Tkinter.